# How do I get my client to talk to my server?

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

I have a Client and Server program. When I run this simultaneously on localhost it works but now I have moved the server program to my server hosted on digital Ocean. I want my client and server to communicate when i execute the client program on my laptop.

This is the client code

```
public class ClientExample{
    Socket requestSocket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;
    ClientExample(){}
    void run()
    {
        try{
            //1. creating a socket to connect to the server
            requestSocket = new Socket("182.15.6.1", 2222); //ip is example
            System.out.println("Connected to localhost in port 2004");
            //2. get Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
            //3: Communicating with the server
            do{
                try{
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println("server>" + message);
                    sendMessage("hello!");
                    sendMessage("How are you");
                    message = "bye";
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException classNot){
                    System.err.println("data received in unknown format");
                }
            }while(!message.equals("bye"));
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost){
            System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                requestSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("client>" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ClientExample client = new ClientExample();
        client.run();
    }
}
```

This is my the server code

```
public class ExampleServer{
    ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;
    ExampleServer(){}
    void run()
    {
        try{
            //1. creating a server socket
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2222, 10);
            //2. Wait for connection
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            //3. get Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            sendMessage("Connection successful");
            //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
            do{
                try{
                    message = (String)in.readObject();

                    System.out.println("client>" + message);
                    if (message.equals("bye"))
                        sendMessage("bye");
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                    System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                }
            }while(!message.equals("bye"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                providerSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("server>" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ExampleServer server = new ExampleServer();
        while(true){
            server.run();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at ClientExample.run(ClientExample.java:13)
        at ClientExample.main(ClientExample.java:66)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ClientExample.run(ClientExample.java:43)
        at ClientExample.main(ClientExample.java:66)
```

I was asked to ping the server and this is the result, Seems okay to me.

```
 Pinging MyServer with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from MyServer: bytes=32 time=151ms TTL=50
Reply from MyServer: bytes=32 time=116ms TTL=50
Reply from MyServer: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=50
Reply from MyServer: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for MyServer:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% los
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 98ms, Maximum = 151ms, Average = 116ms
```

Comment: All I can see is that the connection to the server couldn't be established. Then the catch block was executed and printed the 1st stack trace. Then, in finally, the NPE happened due to `in` not having received an InputStream. - Can you ping the server?

Comment: Not related to your error (Neeraj already answered that), but you should look into [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your Server is running on port **2004**

```
providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
                                   /\
                                   ||
```

and your Client is asking for the connection on different port **2222**

```
requestSocket = new Socket("182.15.6.1", 2222); //ip is example
                                          /\
                                          ||
```

and Exception is coming in finally block at line

```
in.close(); // As connection not made so `in` still isn't innitialized
```

Comment: Whoops sorry I actually did change that on the server, both are port 2222. I copied that code from an old version. Apologies, I'm still getting that error, could it be my firewall or anything?